# Padding in website

Tags: css, web, padding

I am developing a website, and it appeared a "ghost" padding, that is not declared in the website, or at least i didn't declared it, i checked the plugins and the code i inserted, i tried to see if it was a sidebar that was appearing in the code , but not being shown but the padding is still there.

http://nobre.webexperts.pt

I wonder how can this be solved, thanks in advance.

I am using the theme: royalstartex theme ( that doesn't have already support ) it is based on klasik theme.

Comment: Where the padding is declared?

Comment: Where does it appear? I see lots of paddings on your page, but don't know which one you mean. You might try `html,body{margin: 0;padding: 0; }`

Comment: If you say about left padding, it is because you use class 'two columns' to logo and 'ten columns' to all other container.

Comment: Please take a moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the padding for the example is in hte contact page, and in the products page, is after the footer!

Comment: which padding you need to remove.

Comment: when u enter in products the page has 1300px to the footer, after the footer it continues for about 2000px or 1500px, i want to remove that, but the inspector don't identify any element

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are not talking about padding, but about the extra whitespace appearing in the bottom of some pages. That is caused by an `aside` element with the id `sidebar` being placed far below the content. Remove whatever plugin/widget is placing a sidebar there!

Comment: Thanks fot the solution mate, i thought using class sidebar and saying it for it not be visible and with height 0 was enough but seems like not